# Soon to be PhD Applied Math graduate looking to emigrate UK for better life quality. Just not sure where?

Tags: job-hunting

Soon to be PhD Applied Math graduate looking to emigrate from UK. I hold a British passport and hence have access to the EU countries.

Unfortunately the UK doesn't seem to treat its STEM graduates very well. Given the number of years of education it has taken to gain these skills, and factoring in both the cost and lack of earning, the  compensation and stability is really very poor; particular so in engineering and academia. Let me be clear that I'm not looking to become mega rich or a free ride, however with the house prices, rental and living costs etc a middle class lifestyle in the UK is all but dead for my generation. I am also looking at quantitative finance jobs, however they are getting harder to come by.

I am therefore looking to emigrate from UK, however I'm really struggling to find information on  PhD level jobs abroad in countries that offer a good standard of living. Has anyone else in a similar situation made this leap? Are there any website that offer advice?

Comment: Do you speak any other languages?

Comment: As it stands this is too broad, with far too many possible answers.  Are you looking for English only? Are you over 30? Do you care about culture, climate etc? There are literally thousands of emigration/transition websites.  Please have a look at the [help] and see if you can isolate your question to a specific issue - it's totally fine to make more posts, but as we're still in beta we're very strict about specific problem/solution posts.